# Software testing: Clustering algorithm from clusters / Boolean series

Tags: clustering, missing-data

I have a set of around 6000 tests that measure whether software is ready to ship to production. Each time a software build is created I get a pass or fail result for each test. Tests are added and removed from time to time, so I have a table where each row is a test case and each column is a software build version. Each cell is either a pass, a fail, or a "not run" state for that test and build.

I want to cluster tests together that fail together across the set of software builds. If I know that a set of tests usually fail together, I want to be able to select and run the fastest and most reliable tests from the cluster first.

I guess I ultimately want the algorithm to identify tests that have a common root cause so that I can run the test that identifies that root cause first and get feedback as quickly as possible. However, each test is affected by multiple root causes and may fail in concert with different sets of other tests depending on the root causes present in the system at any given time. Each set of failed tests gives me a snapshot which I think can use to build up the certainty that tests are either strongly related to each other or only weakly related to each other in terms of how often they fail together. The root cause is usually going to be a software defect that affects multiple tests, but will sometimes be something like a failed server or network connection. Environmental failures will typically affect a large number of tests whereas software defects will typically affect a smaller number of tests.

I'm pretty unclear about the right algorithm to find these tests that fail together or the right way to think about them. Should I be looking for a Boolean/binary clustering algorithm, or should I be thinking of this more as a set of probable predefined clusters (the set of failed tests for any given build) and trying to average these clusters out somehow to get a clearer set of tests that fail together?

Comment: `some uncertainty in my dataset because...` Can you identify these cases of "environmental failures"?

Comment: Your idea to cluster analyze tests seems fine, but you have a problem of missing data: not every test was performed on all the builds.

Comment: For this kind of data I would look into correspondence analysis, and there must be some way to combine that with clustering, see for example https://econ-papers.upf.edu/papers/1626.pdf